# Generate hooks for selected functions in Python Abstract Base Class

Tags: python, abstract-class

I have Python ABC like,

```py
class Foo(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def bar(self):
        ...

    @abstractmethod
    def baz(self):
        ...
```

When I initialize it, I want to implement the hooks without defining them in the parent class, and they will also run in order, is this possible?

```py
class FooChild(Foo):
    def pre_bar(self): # not defined in parent but will run as well
        ...

    def bar(self):
        ...

    def post_bar(self):
        ...
```

So when I run

```py
foo_child = FooChild()
foo_child.bar()
```

`pre_bar` and `post_bar` will also run automatically.

Comment: Can't you just call them in `.bar()`? This seems to be an oversimplified version which does not reflect your actual situation. Could you edit the the question to include more context?

Comment: This is actually what I want to do with my codebase, I have ~10 class methods within the parent class and I don't want to let the children edit the behavior of the methods but I want to leave some flexibility, and I'm too lazy to type the `pre_` and `post_` functions for each of them, so I'm looking to see if there's alternative to that, but yes I can also go with the approach of calling them within the `bar` function